# How to perform as.data.frame.matrix method on SparkR's object 'Formal DataFrame'

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I want to perform method:

as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~name + value, table))

In Rstudio on data.frame objects it works quite cool.
I have a data.frame 'table' as follows:

```
> table
     name    value 
[1,] "user1" "less"
[2,] "user1" "more"
[3,] "user1" "agua"
[4,] "user1" "dog" 
[5,] "user2" "less"
[6,] "user2" "agua"
[7,] "user2" "dog"
```

Performing: `ans <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~name+value, table))`
I have obtained result as follow:

```
> ans
      agua dog less more
user1    1   1    1    1
user2    1   1    1    0
```

Do you know how can I get same result on SparkR basing on Formal DataFrame object, not on data.frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Spark `DataFrame` is not compatible with standard R functions and cannot be used to replace `data.frame`.

Comment: I know that i cannot use exactly the same function to do this, but i'm wondering how - if it is possible - can i perform such transformation (ie. using sql queries or sth else)